# Regex in php - preg_replace issues

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to catch and replace a regex in a variable but I'm getting some troubles. 
The regex I'm trying to catch is a pattern like that :

one or many letters (one or many numbers (may have a .) one or many numbers) one or many letters

What I'm trying to do is to replace the whole string with only figures in it. Here's an example :

6Â Â° C => 6
1015.12 hPa => 1015.12
distance 172.1 km => 172.1

And here is my regex so far (don't blame me, I'm not really into regex haha) :

```
$test = preg_replace('#([a-zA-Z]*([0-9]*(\.)*[0-9]*)[a-zA-Z]*)#i', '$2', $myString);
```

Thanks in advance for you help !

Comment: so you only want to keep the numbers and letters where they belong?

Comment: What result do you exactly want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/","", $string);`

Comment: Thank you !! I didn't think to think that way (delete everything which is not interessing) !

Comment: then close your question please

Comment: @alexbts, if this answer satisfied your needs you should accept it by activating the check mark on the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

It seems I found the answer. My pattern wasn't correct, here's a good one :

**'#[\D]*([0-9]*(.)*[0-9]*)[\D]*#i'**